# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment -ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Aight so I just started to learn react and I wanted to make a blog and the elements of the blog are in an array and I show the blog posts by a map function the problem is when I add something to the map function it gives me this error:

```
Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment


   6 |          {blog.map ( (blogs) => {return (<h2>{blogs.title}</h2> 
   7 |
>  8 |              <button>Delete post</button>
     |              ^
   9 |          )})}
```

and here is the code

```
const Blog_tem = (props) => {
    const blog = props.blogs;

    return (
        <div className='blog_tem'>
            {blog.map ( (blogs) => {return (<h2>{blogs.title}</h2> 

                <button>Delete post</button>
            )})}



        </div>
    );
}
export default Blog_tem;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each map item should have only one root element (https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

```
{blog.map((blogs, i) => (
  <div key={i}>
    <h2>{blogs.title}</h2> 
    <button>Delete post</button>
  </div>
))}

// with fragment if you don't want an extra element
{blog.map((blogs, i) => (
  <React.Fragment key={i}>
    <h2>{blogs.title}</h2> 
    <button>Delete post</button>
  </React.Fragment>
))}
```

I used array index as key but you should use a more consistent variable, like blog id.